# Child route doesn't work with empty route path

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to create a route to the profile page of a user, which must be "/:username", but it doesn't work. It is described on the last line. It seems that the child routes don't work with parents that have an empty path.

**app.js**

```
configureRouter(config, router){
        config.title = 'Dreampper';
        //config.options.pushState = true;
        config.map([
          { route: '',              moduleId: 'home'},
          { route: 'login', moduleId: './components/account/login', name: 'login'},
          { route: 'register', moduleId: './components/account/register', name: 'register'}
        ]);
```

In my **home.js** I have:

```
{ route: '', moduleId: './components/timeline/timeline', name: 'timeline' },
{ route: 'welcome', moduleId: './components/account/welcome', name: 'welcome' },
{ route: 'account/EmailConfirmation/:user/:code',  moduleId: './components/account/email-confirmation', name:'Email confirmation' },
{ route: ':username', moduleId: './components/profile/profile', name: 'profile' }
```

Someone could help me? I don't want to use redirect, because the redirect makes the URL doesn't be empty "localhost/".

Comment: It doesn't work because it leads to some problems. Let's suppose that your user is named "welcome". So, the route would be `/welcome`. However, you already have a route named `welcome`. There's is no way to identify which route you are trying to get, `/:username` or `/welcome`. You should use something like `/profile/:username`

Comment: @Felipe, were you able to get this solved?

Comment: Hello @FabioLuz and LStarky, I shouldn't worry about having a route "welcome" and a username "welcome". This is a responsibility of the API, not allowing users to have the same name as the routes. I'm still trying something to make it work. I'll try the LStarky suggestion and then report to you.

Comment: FelipeSantana I know it's been a while, but you have to understand that a route of ':username' is the equivalent of a route that matches ANYTHING except the empty string. This is why the Aurelia router cannot work in this case. As @FabioLuz mentioned, the string 'welcome' matches both the 'welcome route and the 'profile' route. At this point, Aurelia isn't sure which route takes precedence, b/c both routes are EXACT matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mapUnknownRoutes` function when you configure your router.  I didn't test this but you should be able to do something like this.  Please also take into account Fabio's suggestion -- it's a good one.  But if you really want to do it...

```
config.mapUnknownRoutes({ redirect: '#/' });

router.configure(config => {
  config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {
    //check instruction.fragment
    //set instruction.config.moduleId
  });
});
```

Basically you'll want to look at the instruction.fragment to get the actual route that was specified, and then redirect it to a particular route with the parameter as whatever route was given.